# Integral versus hypergeometric series: how to solve this?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

How can I resolve the following indefinite integral using hypergeometric series?

$$
\int (x^3 + 1)^\frac{1}{3} \,dx
$$

Wolfram Alpha indicates that the series of Appell are used, but how to get to this result?

Grateful!

Comment: Ask WA  to compute instead $\displaystyle\int\left(1+x^p\right)^q dx$ without specifying what $p$ and $q$ are.

Answer (score 3):

> *But how to get to this result?*

By expanding the integrand into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and switching the order of summation and integration.

Comment: However this will give a much simpler expression (Mathematica is stupid).

Comment: Namely, $x {}_2F_1\left(\frac13,-\frac13,\frac43,-x^3\right)$.

Comment: @O.L.: *Maple* returns a nicer result. I guess that *Mathematica* jumps directly at Appell functions since the exponent there is $\dfrac13$.